# How can I exhaust all parameter combinations of a function and gather their results in one tidy table?

Tags: r, tidyverse, broom

```
library(fpp2) # for prison dataset
library(hts) # forecasting function

# prepare group time series
prison.gts <- gts(prison/1e3, characters = c(3,1,9),
                  gnames = c("State", "Gender", "Legal",
                             "State*Gender", "State*Legal",
                             "Gender*Legal"))

# run forecasts
forecast.gts(prison.gts, method="bu", fmethod="arima")
forecast.gts(prison.gts, method="comb", fmethod="arima")
forecast.gts(prison.gts, method="bu", fmethod="ets")
forecast.gts(prison.gts, method="comb", fmethod="ets")
forecast.gts(prison.gts, method="bu", fmethod="rw")
forecast.gts(prison.gts, method="comb", fmethod="rw")
```

As you can see, I'm trying all the different values available for these 2 parameters 'method' and 'fmethod' to compare the forecast results.

Is there a simpler way I can do this in tidyverse format?
Basically I want to create a list of all parameter combinations, gather their results in one table.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Using `tidyverse` methods you could do use `crossing` to create all combinations of `methods`  and `fmethod`. We can use `map2` to apply `forecast.gts` function to each combination.

```
library(fpp2) 
library(hts)
library(dplyr)

result_obj <- tidyr::crossing(methods = c('bu', 'comb'), 
                              fmethod = c('arima', 'ets', 'rw')) %>%
                  mutate(forecast_result = purrr::map2(methods, fmethod, 
                      ~forecast.gts(prison.gts,method = .x, fmethod = .y)))
```

Comment: Is there any way to extract the vector of acceptable values for a particular parameter? For example, in this example, we're hardcoding the values for methods and fmethod. In fact, in the documentation, the acceptable values are much more.

Comment: Error in purrr::map2(methods, method, ~forecast.gts(prison.gts, method = .x,  : 
  object 'method' not found, could you please check again on the code. Thanks

Comment: From where you want to extract it? It is not stored anywhere. There was a typo there, I have corrected it now.

Comment: Ok, I fixed the code, replaced 'method' as 'fmethod' purrr::map2(methods, fmethod... But I notice that the runtime is extremely slow compared to running the forecast one by one. Is there a good explanation to this? Thank you

Comment: Is that so? I am not sure which part of the code would be making it slow.

Comment: Thanks, I'll accept this answer as it answer the main question. Thanks again! :)